# Resetting Windows 10 - worried about my personal files

Tags: windows-10

I need to reset my windows, but I'm worried about my files.
I have two partitions, both encrypted with BitLocker: one (C:) where Windows is installed and another one (E:) with my files.

That folders we have in (C:)UserProfile is linked to E:\
So I have:
Music -> E:\username\Music
Videos -> E:\username\Videos
Documents -> E:\username\Documents
OneDrive -> E:\username\OneDrive

When resetting we have two options: "Keep my files" or "Remove everything".
If I choose to "Remove everything", will it remove my files on E: partition?
Or, if I choose to "Keep my files", will it create a copy of everything (hundreds of GB) on C: partition?

Sorry for the lame question.

Comment: Just create an additional Backup before resetting...

Comment: Anything uploaded to OneDrive will stay there, so you already have an off-site backup. Once you've re-installed Windows, log in to OneDrive and the files will sync back down. For added peace of mind, make a new folder `e:\backup\` and copy the music and videos in, but it's highly unlikely a re-install would remove them.

Comment: `Reset` only touches the system partition.  You will want to disable BitLocker on your system partition.  You will want to backup your recovery key for your other partition.  As with any operation, you will want to backup any critical data, in the event something goes wrong.  **If you choose `Remove Everything` nothing on your system partition will be saved.**